# MySQL - Revenue Current vs Prior Month by client

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if someone could help me workout MySQL version 5.7.22 script for retrieving current and previous month revenue in one table grouped by Date and AccountID

I have the following headers from inner joins from other tables

- Date (last day of month)
- AccountName
- Revenue

What I have so far

```
Select 

Last_Day(Invoice.Date) AS 'DATE', 
Client.Id as ACCOUNTID, 
CLIENT NAME,  
Sum(Subtotal) AS 'REVENUE'

FROM Invoice

INNER JOIN Clients ON Clients.Id = Invoice.Id


GROUP BY 
Last_Day(Invoice.Date),
Clients.Id

ORDER BY
Invoice.Date desc
```

What I expect

```
Select 


Last_Day(Invoice.Date) AS 'DATE', 
Client.Id as ACCOUNTID, 
CLIENT NAME,  
Sum(Subtotal) AS 'REVENUE'
Sum(Subtotal) AS 'PMREVENUE' <-- this to be previous month revenue record per client

FROM Invoice

INNER JOIN Clients ON Clients.Id = Invoice.Id


GROUP BY 
Last_Day(Invoice.Date),
Clients.Id

ORDER BY
Invoice.Date desc
```

[Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnU5i.png)

Assume I know nothing
Note: I cannot use LAG or WITH due to version
Thank you in Advance

Comment: please don't post data as images see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Unless you have very unusual naming conventions for your columns, It is very unlikely that Clients.Id and Invoice.Id are the correct join keys for those two tables.

Comment: I had to inner join purley for the invoice date as this is not stored in the client table which contains the Name/Id just the primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only concerned about the current month and the previous month, you can do this:

```
Select 
    Last_Day(Invoice.Date) AS 'DATE', 
    Client.Id as ACCOUNTID, 
    `CLIENT NAME`,  
    Sum(CASE WHEN Last_Day(Invoice.Date)=Last_Day(CURDATE()) THEN Subtotal ELSE 0 END) AS 'REVENUE'
    Sum(CASE WHEN Last_Day(Invoice.Date)=Last_Day(DATE_ADD(DATE(), INTERVAL  -1 MONTH) THEN Subtotal ELSE 0 END) AS 'PMREVENUE' 
FROM Invoice
INNER JOIN Clients ON Clients.Id = Invoice.Id

GROUP BY 
Clients.Id
```

If your report needs to return every month, then you need to do this:

```
WITH MonthEnd AS (
Select 
    Last_Day(Invoice.Date) AS 'DATE', 
    Client.Id as ACCOUNTID, 
    `CLIENT NAME`,  
    Sum(Subtotal) AS 'REVENUE'
FROM Invoice
INNER JOIN Clients ON Clients.Id = Invoice.Id

GROUP BY 
    Last_Day(Invoice.Date),
    Clients.Id
)
SELECT CURRENT.DATE, 
    CURRENT.ACCOUNTID, 
    CURRENT.`CLIENT NAME`, 
    CURRENT.REVENUE, 
    PREVIOUS.REVENUE AS PMREVENUE
FROM MonthEnd AS CURRENT
JOIN MonthEnd AS PREVIOUS ON PREVIOUS.`DATE` = LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(CURRENT.`DATE`, INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
                          AND CURRENT.ACCOUNTID=PREVIOUS.ACCOUNTID
ORDER BY CURRENT.`DATE` DESC
```

EDIT: Doing this Without WITH is just a matter of replacing the reference to the CTE with a subquery:

```
SELECT CURRENT.DATE, 
    CURRENT.ACCOUNTID, 
    CURRENT.`CLIENT NAME`, 
    CURRENT.REVENUE, 
    PREVIOUS.REVENUE AS PMREVENUE
FROM (
    Select 
        Last_Day(Invoice.Date) AS 'DATE', 
        Client.Id as ACCOUNTID, 
        `CLIENT NAME`,  
        Sum(Subtotal) AS 'REVENUE'
    FROM Invoice
    INNER JOIN Clients ON Clients.Id = Invoice.Id

    GROUP BY 
        Last_Day(Invoice.Date),
        Clients.Id
) AS CURRENT
JOIN (
    Select 
        Last_Day(Invoice.Date) AS 'DATE', 
        Client.Id as ACCOUNTID, 
        `CLIENT NAME`,  
        Sum(Subtotal) AS 'REVENUE'
    FROM Invoice
    INNER JOIN Clients ON Clients.Id = Invoice.Id

    GROUP BY 
        Last_Day(Invoice.Date),
        Clients.Id
    ) AS PREVIOUS ON PREVIOUS.`DATE` = LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(CURRENT.`DATE`, INTERVAL -1 MONTH))
                          AND CURRENT.ACCOUNTID=PREVIOUS.ACCOUNTID
ORDER BY CURRENT.`DATE` DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for this! 
I have such an outdated version of MySQL server it doesn’t let me use WITH.

Comment: I have edited my answer to do this without WITH

Comment: thanks for this update again - sorry havent had time to test this until today. The last part does not work says syntax error 'AS PREVIOUS ON PREVIOUS.`DATE` = LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(CURRENT.`DATE`, INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
                          AND CURRENT.ACCOUNTID=PREVIOUS.ACCOUNTID'

Comment: Oops,  it looks like I missed a close parentheses.  I have fixed that error.